# VBA: set txt to be printed in Portrait mode

Tags: vba, text, printing, text-editor

this time I'm fighting against a .txt file which doesn't want to be (programmatically) set to be printed in Portrait-mode instead of Landscape-mode (which is the default apparently).

Thing is I know how to do that with application like Word or Excel, but sadly enough I'm working on a device that has no Office at all.

I'm not providing any code at all since my problem is pretty straightforward, and I think I need a simple command in order to solve it. What I basically (programmatically) do in my subroutine is:

- Open the file as #1 (I know this appears so '80, but I don't want to modify an up-and-running system, potentially having errors show up)
- Write text to the file
- Close #1
- Save the file
- Call text editor shell to show the file to the user

How can I then automatically set the print format to Portrait?

P.s.= I do not have the possibility to insert a userform or an object to print the txt file in "special ways", the user has to print the file from txt editor itself (wordpad just in case)

Comment: You've tagged this [VBA] but you say you don't have Office on the device.  What language are you writing in?  And (most importantly), which text editor are we talking about?

Comment: Well VBA is Visual Basic for Applications... not only for Office.
I am programming in VBA and my application is has its native VB commands (like those in excel). You want to know the device? A network analyzer even though this doesn't bring any useful info.

About the text editor, the machine runs on Windows, so the text editor is notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to state the obvious: there are no print settings stored in text files (or indeed anything else except for the text).  Print settings would be controlled within whatever you are using to print - in this case Notepad or Wordpad.

There are only very limited command line switches for [Notepad](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389) and [Wordpad](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Wordpad), which unfortunately don't include page setup.  In theory you *may* be able to automate setting portrait using `SendKeys` (see [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?620479-SendKey-to-other-process) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/e40c9faa-0009-4293-bfa8-5438689b9a05/wordpad-automation)) but if it is possible at all it's likely to be difficult and unreliable (focus and timing are two issues).

I can't see a good way round this within the parameters of your question.  Adding an object within your application would probably have been the best solution.  You might try looking for an alternative text editor you could install that is easier to automate.  The only other alternative might be to set defaults within the printer drivers and hope that those stick when the user opens Notepad.

Comment: I take it as a "no you can't" :)
Unfortunately the possibilities that I have with that hardware are really limited and it's not possible to install any other software...

Comment: I've added another suggestion, but other than that I can't think of anything (I have been known to be wrong...but no-one else has come up with anything either!)

Comment: The problem with making changes within the printer drivers is that would have to be done for each machine, and would affect the default for all printing.